# Working with array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Question: Develop an array of 1000 objects (having properties name and number as shown).

1. We need a function to convert every object so the name is uppercased
   and values are 5 times the original and store into the *higher*
   variable. Similarly, another function that converts every object so
   the name is lower case and value is 3 times the original, store this
   into the *little* variable.
2. We need a function that takes each object in *higher* and finds all
   objects in *little* that evenly divide into it. Example: 30 in
   *higher* object is evenly divided by 6 in *little*.
3. The output of 2 must be an array of *higher* numbers, and in every
   object there should be `got` (which is a variable inside the object) which will contain every *little*
   object that evenly divided the *higher*.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<script>
    var n = 1000;
var sample = [];
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) sample.push({
   name:'John' + i,
   value: i 
});
console.log(sample);

function Converter() {
    var n = 1000;
    var higher = sample;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) higher.name = 'John' + i;
    higher.value = i * 5;
    console.log(higher);
}
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The array of objects is created and it is as expected/required by the question, however, the `converter` function for `higher` does not work, also how should the 3rd question be done?

Comment: `sample` is the array, not an item inside the array. When you access `higher.name` and `higher.value` you are accessing an undefined property in the array. Also, your syntax is not correct, `for` has missing braces and you probably didn't intend to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

1) only constructors should start with a capital letter, functions should be camelcase by convention so it should be `converter`

2) you don't call `converter()` so it never gets executed

3) make sure to indent your code properly `var n` and `var sample` should be at the same depth.

4) if you omit the brackets after an `if` or `for`, only the following statement gets inside the branch, so in your case you do:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
     higher.name = 'John'+i;
 higher.value = i*5;
```

so the second line isn't even executed in the loop, you want:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    higher.name = 'John'+i;
    higher.value = i*5;
}
```

5) `higher.name` makes little sense as `higher` is an array, you want to change the name of the `i`th `higher` number which you can do with `higher[i].name`

6) `"John1"` is not in caps, you want to call `toUpperCase` on it (`("John1").toUpperCase()`)

> also how should the 3rd question be done?

I guess fixing your code and doing the second question is enough for today.

You could continue reading:

[Coding style matters](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/why-coding-style-matters/)

[js array iterations](http://2ality.com/2011/04/iterating-over-arrays-and-objects-in.html?showComment=1373837092717)

Comment: How should I proceed with the 2nd question? I think I have to compare 2 arrays. This is one of the main questions that I'm stuck at.

Comment: @john first fix your code!! make yourself familiar with the console and the tools, get some more basics. You haven't even found the most basic errors in your code, you cannot write more conplex code without failing completely. Do it step by step.

Comment: Is it appropriate to suggest `Array.prototype.map` or will that be too much?

Comment: @slider if you look at john's question history, one can clearly see that he is dumping is homework here, full of typos & syntax errors and the community produces clean and copy+paste ready answers ... The array methods are definetly good to point out but I would not give any code.

Answer (score 1):

You should also try to think in a more structured manner about your code here. I would suggest writing separate functions for each problem and giving them meaningful names. Perhaps something like the following:

```
var n = 1000;
var sample = [];
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) sample.push({
    name: 'John' + i,
    value: i
});
console.log(sample);

var higher = convertToHigher(sample);
var little = convertToLittle(sample);
var higherWithDivisors = findAllDivisors(higher, little);

function convertToHigher(arr) {
    var newArr = [];
    // TODO: iterate through each entry in arr, create a new modified object 
    // with a higher value and add it to newArr
    return newArr;
}

function convertToLittle(arr) {
    var newArr = [];
    // TODO: iterate through each entry in arr, create a new modified object
    // with a lower value and add it to newArr
    return newArr;
}

function findAllDivisors(arr1, arr2) {
    var newArr = [];
    // TODO: solve problem 3 here
    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: Thank-you @slider. I tried to develop `convertToHigher`, however, it does not work. The code                                                                                              `function convertToHigher(arr){  
      var newArr = [];  
      var n = 1000;  
      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){  
      arr[i].name = 'JOHN' + i;  
      arr.value = i * 5;   
      }  
  
      console.log(arr);  
      return newArray;  
  }`